# To hide the default footer and show the footer defined in specific page in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the footer bar added in the index.html file

```
 <ion-footer-bar  align-title="left" class="bar-assertive zee-footer" ng-show="loggedUser && loggedUser > 0">
    <div class="buttons {{footerTabSee}}">
        <button class="button btn-relative" ng-click="seePage()"><img src="img/pen-white.png" alt=""/>
           <span id="seeNoti"></span>
            <!--<span class="btn-notification">1</span>-->
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons {{footerTabHeart}}">
        <button class="button " ng-click="heartPage()"> <img src="img/single-heart.png" alt=""/> </button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons foo-rose {{footerTabChat}}">
        <button class="button"  ng-click="rosePage()"> <img src="img/rose.png" alt=""/>
            <!--<span class="btn-notification" ng-show="roseNotification">{{roseNotification}}</span>-->
            <span id="roseNoti"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
    <div class="buttons {{footerTabChatGrp}}">
        <button class="button "> <img src="img/double-heart.png" alt=""/> </button>
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

this footer is displayed in all the files in my project, but in one page i don't want this footer. I want to add my custom footer that will be in the page itself.

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable item-input-inset chat-page chat-footer" keyboard-attach>
    <!--<div class="chat-camera"  ng-show="msgData.txt == ''"></div>-->
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <textarea msd-elastic name="msgData.txt" ng-model="msgData.txt" ng-blur="" placeholder="Write here..."></textarea>
    </label>
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-send chat-send" ng-disabled="!msgData.txt || msgData.txt === ''" ng-click="sendMessage(User.other_chat_id)"></button>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is `loggedUser` in `ng-show` of main footer?